# Where do I find the latest version of the QtQuick2 libraries?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm new to Qt/QML/Qt Quick.

I have Qt 5.14 and QtCreator installed and am attempting to build a sample application.

Currently I have QtQuick 2.12 installed (which came with the QtCreator installation).

How/where do I get the latest version of the QtQuick2 libraries and make them
accessible to QtCreator?

What is the latest version of QtQuick2?

Answer (score 0):

Change `import QtQuick 2.12` to `import QtQuick 2.14`.

---

#### TL; DR;

Before responding you should know the following:

- If you have Qt 5.14 then you must have the most up-to-date components of Qt (stable version).
- When you create your project Qt Creator will choose the version of the components depending on the configuration you set in the wizard, but you can change it manually: `import QtQuick 2.14`.

As the last stable version points out is Qt 5.14 that contains all the most up-to-date stable components, if you want to use the components of a developing version such as Qt 5.15 then you must download the source code and compile it which can be complicated if you are a beginner.

Comment: I was interested in using the SplitView control which needs QtQuick 2.14. At one point this was working. I am importing QtQuick 2.14. I recently did an update through QtCreator. This might have messed things up. I have Qt Creator 4.11.0

Comment: @JohnB what SplitView: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-splitview.html or https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qml-qtquick-controls2-splitview.html?

Comment: doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/… (The second option from above)

Comment: @JohnB then add `import QtQuick.Controls 2.5`

Comment: What resource are you using to figure this out? This is a silly question - is 2.5 a more recent version/release than 2.14?

Comment: @JohnB The docs points it out: https://i.imgur.com/LwNNH1s.png

Comment: To use QtQuick 2.14, do I have to install Qt5.5? I have a feeling that when I did an update, it might have wiped out a previous installation of Qt5.5.

Comment: @JohnB QtQuick 5.14 comes in Qt 5.14 so it has nothing to do with Qt 5.5